# SharedPreference not saving with commit on android 16

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm having a very weird problem that only happens on android 16 and not in android 27 [i didn't test other version to check where it starts]

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication()).edit();

     edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_custom_list), false);
      edit.putStringSet(getString(R.string.pref_username_list_, getCurrentUser().getAuth().getUserId()), imported);
 edit.commit();
System.exit(1);
```

Imported is a `Set<String>`

when i restart the app and try to read

```
 final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplication());

final Set<String> cachedList = pref.getStringSet(getString(R.string.pref_username_list_, userid), new HashSet<String>(APIFacade.CACHE_SIZE));
```

On android 16 i get an empty set, but on 27 everything is fine

what might be?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to:

```
System.exit(1);
```

You shouldn't be calling that from an application. That will immediately terminate your process, so it doesn't surprise me that you're running into unexpected behavior. You're likely killing the process before it's able to commit your changes to disk. It might just be quick enough on newer devices that you're avoiding the issue.

Whatever Activity you're running this code from should simply call `finish()` when you want your app's UI to be dismissed, rather than trying to terminate your process.

Comment: `commit()` is supposed to be a synchronous method... so it should only return after the changes are on disk

Comment: While that's true, I would still recommend trying without the call to `System.exit()`.

Comment: Anyway, the code i put on example is just a simplification, in the real code there is an alertdialog asking the user if he want the changes take place now... and there is enough time to commit a hell of data